# Where does a compiled program go?

Tags: installation, wine, compiling

I followed instructions to download `wine 1.7.1` source to apply a patch to insert into *playonlinux*.

The compiling seems to go well, it says build complete at the end. But now what? The source folder has a million things in it. How do I know it even worked right?

Note: I don't want to replace my default wine, or I would do make install like the instructions say. I want to insert it into *playonlinux* to use as a prefix

Commands that I've used:

```
cd wine-1.7.1    
wget -q http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6901628/disable-dynamic-vertex-buffers.patch  -O - | patch -p1    
./configure    
make
```

Comment: What are you compiling? Could you provide a link to the source? You will know that the compilation finished right if you don't get an error message, that's all. The compilation files will be stored in the folder that you are running on (if you didn't changed this)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/Source/wine-1.7.1.tar.bz2/download

Comment: What do you mean with *I don't want to replace my default wine*? Aren't you trying to install Wine?

Comment: Right, but where do the actual compiled files go? Is there a way to put them in another folder?

Comment: I have wine installed from the ppa, and I don't want to mess with it. I'm trying to use it just for playonlinux...with a special patch

Comment: Please, *edit* your question and show us what commands are you using.

Comment: Ok does that help? =-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Some Info

When you compile a program from scratch, the end result will be one or more [*binary files*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) for the program. These are computer readable files that do not contain code or text, though they may use other text files. Think of it as describing a picture, with words (the code), to an artist (the computer) so he can then make the final result (the binary file).

Most system installed binaries are in `/usr/bin`. When you invoke a terminal command that begins with a command rather than a file name (which may or may not be a binary file), it will look in `/usr/bin` for the binary and run it. For example, `ls` in the terminal will actually invoke the `/usr/bin/ls` binary file.

If you want to run an .exe with wine, for example, you would use `./bin/wine [exe file]`. This demonstrates that the binary will not have a file name extension.

#### Where are binary files put?

Anyway, these binary files are usually located in the `./bin` folder in the source tree after compiling, unless you used the `--prefix` option with `./configure`. With Wine, it may be different, perhaps check `./wine/bin`.

Comment: That's the thing, there is no bin folder in the source folder after compiling, nor is there a .bin folder in .wine. I tried using a prefix to install into a different folder in my home directory, but after compiling it remained empty. Kind of frustrating.

Comment: What are the folder names you see in the source directory? I wasn't suggesting looking in `~/.wine`, but perhaps in the `wine/` folder in the source folder.

Comment: libs, server, fonts, documentation, tools, dlls, include, po, programs, loader, doc-pak...inside the wine folder are a bunch of files like, c_437.o for example, the wine folder is inside of libs...nothing i know what to do with

Comment: I figured it out, I wasn't doing make install into the prefix. *slaps forehead* Thanks for the help guys